# packages being erased when adding new packages into repository

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

just like the title says, I have a problem with certain packages being deleted when I introduce new packages in my repo. An example would be: react-redux is added into my repo and image-compressor.js is then deleted from my repo. another issue with this is i've been trying to add an image-cropper onto my web-app and it seems to delete the react-player package I added a couple months ago. Not sure why this is happening. I cant seem to find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "being removed" are you looking into your `node_modules` folder to look for them? what version of npm / yarn, node are you using?

Comment: node -v v12.16.2
yarn 1.19.2

it seems to remove the entire package from my repo. ive checked in node_modules and cant find them at all.

Comment: so i understand correclty, you have added node_modules to git and are checking for the modules in your repo in github or something?

Comment: yes, and in turn when i add a new module, other specific ones are erased. ei: react-redux--->react-image-compressor

Comment: I think its safe to assume that this doesn't happen locally then? I would add `node_modules` to your  `.gitignore` file, I don't think the issue you are encountering has any real affect, it might just be that github is removing certain modules with security issues or something. in any case there's no need to be adding node_modules in your repo